# Drupal 8: Adding classes to the body tag so i can adress it with css

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm curently working on my first drupal 8 site and I'm kinda stuck on trying to add classes to the body tag so I can adress it with css.

in drupal 7 you can have like "node-4" as a class but I can't seem to get it working with drupal 8, can anyone help me out? I tried a lot of things already but none of it seems to work so far.

Comment: Please show us where you're at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In themename.theme

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'page-node-' . $node->id();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's different with this code and some code I tried earlyer but this works like a charm!! Thanks so much!!